# Is it allowed that the same address miner mine two blocks with the same block height at the same time?

Tags: addresses, timestamp

I have the question after viewing the following two blocks. I post the url here:

1. https://cn.etherscan.com/block/13821587 This block is in the main chain at the height of 13821587.
2. https://cn.etherscan.com/uncle/0x9ec78c3ec778333389681b7c2ce9c05b170b1d5314ae0ff49a6cc06b6c89271e This block is the uncle block at the same height of 13821587.

It's quiet weird that this two block are from the same miner address and created at the same time(12/17/2021 8:25:17 AM +UTC).The only different attribute is the hash value.

I would be appreciate if you can help me to understand this situation. Thank you.

Comment: It is not forbidden. Miners are usually distributed networks so it isn't rare that two computers from the same miner mine different blocks at the same height.

Comment: Thank you!!! But is it normal that these two blocks have the same timestamp ?

Comment: YES after grab the data from etherum. The truth is it's normal. It happens everyday.

Comment: It will be nice if you could write that as answer. It somehow make sense since block's time is in seconds (unix timestamp) and there's an average 13 seconds between blocks.

Comment: Ohhhh, so sorry I haven't logged into this website for a long time, could you tell me how can I take your comment as an answer? You help me a lot!!! Thank you so much! But I don't know how to set your comment to be the answer of this problem.